# Fill a table in html with angular 5

Tags: angular, html, css, angular5

I fill an HTML table with angular 5, I use just one parameter " champResultat " to fill all the cells of the table, and by default the values are all displayed on the left side of the cell of table, but i want to display some cells to the right of the cell and the others to the left.

```
<div id="div_1"
        #elementTableResultat
        [ngClass]="estOngletResultatChoisi ? 'table-principale' : 'table-ligne-assocciee'"
        [class.table-ligne-assocciee-cache]="!estAfficheResultat">
        <div class="entete-resultat"></div>
        <tableau-entete-fixe
            id="div_tableau_2"
            *ngIf="estAfficheResultat"
            scrollTermine
            (onScrollTermine)="onScrollResultat()"
            [listeColonne]="listeEnteteColonne">

            <ng-container id="ng_container_8" *ngIf="estLignesEcrituresGroupees; else lignesResultatSimple">
                <tbody id="tbody_1"
                    *ngFor="let ecritureLigneResultat of mapLigneResultat | mapIterateur"
                    [class.est-journal]="estOngletResultatChoisi">
                    <tr id="tr_2"
                        *ngFor="let ligneResultat of ecritureLigneResultat"
                        (click)="positionnerResultat(ligneResultat)"
                        [class.tr-est-ligne-ignoree]="ligneResultat.etatLigne === EtatLigne.Ignore"
                        [class.tr-est-ligne-selectionne]="ligneResultatSelectionnee && ligneResultat.ligneId === ligneResultatSelectionnee.ligneId">
                        <td id="td_1" [ngClass]="EtatLigne[ligneResultat.etatLigne]"></td>
                        <td id="td_champ_donnee_1" class="champ-donnee">{{ ligneResultat.numeroLigneOrigine }}</td>
                        <td id="td_champ_donnee_2"
                            *ngFor="let champResultat of ligneResultat.listeChampResultat"
                            class="champ-donnee">{{ champResultat }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this with **data**?

Comment: I can't because the app is big enough and uses big data

Comment: So you can create small array data not whole data ?

Comment: I find a solution, we can change this 2 line : 

*ngFor="let champResultat of ligneResultat.listeChampResultat; let i = index"
                                [ngClass]="{'champ-donnee': true, 'texte-alignement-droite': monAlignmentColonne[i]===2, 'texte-alignement-centre': monAlignmentColonne[i]===1}"> {{ i + 1 }} - {{ champResultat }}</td>

And in Typescript class, we create a method that will be responsible for defining which column we want to change (according to the name of the column)

it's one of solutions.

Comment: Good luck happy coding :)